# Hide some charts and show other in one report

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have a report with 24 charts, one for each hour of the day. The user can choose to show one, a couple, or all the charts, based on a drop down. The drop down is tied to a parameter that allows multiple values. See below:

[image: Untitled]

The problem is that if the user chooses one or a few hours from the drop down, all the charts show, and the one(s) chosen give data while the others say "no data available".

Currently for each chart I've added the following to show data if the value was chosen in the drop down:

```
=Switch(Parameters!HOURINPUT.Value(0) = "0", false)
```

Is there a way to hide the charts that the user did not choose from the drop down?

It would look nicer to hide the chart and see only the ones chose than have a blank box that says "no data available" in them.

**UPDATE:**

More than one parameter.

[image: Capture]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the only differences between the charts are the hour of the day specified, then I suggest:

- Add a new dataset to the report with values 0 to 23 as selected in the entered `HOURINPUT` parameter - something like: `with cte as (select 0 n union all select n+1 n from cte where n < 23) select n report_hour from cte where n in (@HOURINPUT)`
- Add a new tablix to the report, with a single detail cell only, bound to your new dataset.
- Move one of the existing graphs into the new table's detail cell so that it becomes a subreport, replacing all hard-coded time references in the graph with references to the `report_hour` value from the new dataset.
- You can then remove the other 23 graphs.

In addition to ensuring that graphs are only displayed for the times selected, this should also simplify future maintenance of the report, since any changes required to a graph will only have to be entered onto the one graph (instead of all 24).

Comment: I have more than one parameter. Please see update above. Also, I'm using Oracle if that makes any difference. I tried to using your query to select the values from my HOURINPUT parameter but it did not work. What's the easiest way to select the parameter values to a dataset?

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm finding it difficult to follow your instructions. I need a bit more detail. Could you please provide? I added a new dataset that creates the hours, and I got the HOURINPUT parameter to get it's values from that query. So next you're telling me to remove all my graphs but one, and do what with it?

Comment: @Frank: Yes, it (almost) **always** makes a difference which RDBMS you are using; in the case of Oracle it also depends on which version you are using, since **recursive** CTEs were only introduced in Oracle 11g. (In the absence of a specified RDBMS, it is obvious to assume that SSRS is being used with MS SQLServer.) Also, I said to add a dataset with the values 0 to 23 as selected in the HOURINPUT parameter, not to use the dataset to populate the parameter; so for example, if the user selects the values 0, 3 and 13, the new dataset should return the values 0, 3 and 17.

Comment: @Frank: If you are using Oracle 11g you should simply need to change the `@` to a `:`; if you are using an older version of Oracle, try the following query instead: `select * from (select level-1 report_hour from dual connect by level <= 24) where report_hour in (:HOURINPUT)`. Follow the subsequent steps in the answer above.

Comment: What you're suggesting seems as if it will work, but I'm just having some trouble carry out the steps please help. When you say "Add a new tablix to the report, with a single detail cell only, bound to your new dataset", do you mean create a new report, and for its Category Groups, give the details bound to the new data set? I'm just not too sure what you mean by creating a sub report ...

Comment: I see what you're saying. If I add the new table bound to the new dataset, then when I choose the hour parameter values the appear as they are chosen. But how do I add this to my graphs, so that they show as the user selects the hour parameters?

Comment: @Frank: If you aren't familiar with using subreports in SSRS, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159837%28v=sql.100%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28v=sql.100%29.aspx . Your existing graphs must each be filtering on hard-coded time values; if you change the hard-coded values to values based on a parameter, you can specify the new parameter in the subreport properties Parameters. (If you want help parameterising your hard-coded filtering expression, you will need to supply your hard-coded filtering expression.)